# Need to create a regex to match a UNC administrative share

Tags: regex, unc

I am trying to come up with a regex that will match the following.

```
file://server-name-01/e$/(any file or subfolder)?ds=test_01
```

Below is the expression i've been working with but for some reason this will match any server name.

```
.*[a-zA-Z]:\/\/.*[sf.ps.gdo02].*\?ds=[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$
```

My goal is to match a specific server name and admin share so that any file or subfolder targeted within the share would be a match.

I'm also interested in the ability to match the following using 1 expression.

```
1) file://server-name-01/e$/(any file or subfolder)?ds=test_01
2) file://server-name-02/e$/(any file or subfolder)?ds=test_01
3) file://server-name-03/e$/(any file or subfolder)?ds=test_01
```

Forgive me as i'm fairly new to defining expressions but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: a link for groups: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html  a link for classes: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. I was able to achieve what i was looking for by using the following expression. 'code' ^.*\/\/server.name.\d\d\/.*[Ee]\$\/.*\?ds=.*$

Answer (score 0):

**Regex:**

```
^.*\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\?ds=.*$
```

**[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/lJ4vC7)**

**Example:**

```
file://server-name-01/e$/(any file or subfolder)?ds=test_01
```

**Match:**

```
1    `server-name-01`
2    `e$`
3    `(any file or subfolder)`
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works in Perl.  Not sure if you need more flexibility, but if I understood your requirements correctly, this works (coded it, tested it, pasted in directly).

```
printf("Enter your expression: ");
my $exp = <STDIN>;
chomp($exp);

if ($exp =~ /file:\/\/server-name-0[1-3]\/e\$\/.*\?ds=test_01/)
{
    printf("Matched.\n");
}
else
{
    printf("NO MATCH!\n");
}
```